# How to replace value in map for a key based on a condition in scala

Tags: scala, maps, immutable-collections

I have several immutable map records like :

```
val map = Map("number"->7,"name"->"Jane","city"->"New York")
```

I need to identify the `"name"` key for each record and check its value.If value is `"Jane"` , I need to replace with `"Doe"` and update the map record.

Comment: Please refer to api documentation: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by a simple map operation and pattern matching.

```
scala> val dictionary = Map("number"->7,"name"->"Jane","city"->"New York")
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(number -> 7, name -> Jane, city -> New York)

scala> dictionary map {
     |   case ("name","Jane") => "name" -> "Doe"
     |   case x => x
     | }
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(number -> 7, name -> Doe, city -> New York)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `if else` logic should do the trick

```
map.map(k => {
  if(k._1.toString.equalsIgnoreCase("name") && k._2.toString.equalsIgnoreCase("jane"))
    (k._1, "Doe")
  else
    k
})
```

Or a simple `match case` should do the trick as well as explained by @rogue-one

```
map.map(k => (k._1.toString, k._2.toString) match{
  case ("name", "Jane") => k._1 -> "Doe"
  case _ => k
})
```

Thanks